# How many metrics can be tested in one AB test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ab-test

As part of the AB test, we had a design identical to the one on the screenshot, trying to direct users from the main page to the categories. Because search by query is not as converting and leads people to purchase less.

We developed a design with pictures for each category so that people would focus more on them and launched an experiment.

We got a significant improvement:

- The number of unique users entering the categories increased from 30 to 40% during the experiment, and the sample was large, 100K in each group.

The question is this:

In addition to evaluating the conversion to category, do I need to check other bar metrics.
For example, we had to bring more people into the category, and this share should have affected the entire funnel if you look at the total. Here's a shortened funnel:
DAU
impression_ad
click_ad
click_buy
CTR
%buyer

When comparing these funnels, do I also need to run a test for each metric to confirm whether there is a difference?
It just turns out that there are a lot of metrics to compare, and here we can get a false positive with a higher probability.

Is it possible that when designing, we should choose the %buyer metric at once and try to influence it exclusively, and not look at the rest?

[image]